# how to set value and trigger function in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, mxml

hi so this is my first flash application i have two functions one a click handler to take you to the list page and a function to call the results is there any way in actionscript to pass values through variables like in php($)

what i need to do is to set the function off from the button that is pressed every button needs to supply a different value to the list to get results heres the two functions

```
        protected function button_clickHandler_100():void
    {
        currentState='data';
    }

    protected function dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        getCitysResult.token = cityservice.getCitys(/* VALUE ENTERED HERE */);
    }

    <s:Button click="button_clickHandler_100()" id="button128" includeIn="europe" skinClass="components.englandButton" x="101" y="135"/>
    <s:Button click="button_clickHandler_100()" id="button129" includeIn="europe" skinClass="components.denmarkButton" x="135" y="117"/>
    <s:Button click="button_clickHandler_100()" id="button130" includeIn="europe" skinClass="components.polandButton" x="214" y="135"/>

    <mx:DataGrid includeIn="data" x="28" y="10" id="dataGrid" creationComplete="dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event)" dataProvider="{getCitysResult.lastResult}" width="276" height="255">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="city" dataField="city"/>
    </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

so for instance the vlaue that needs to be supplied is GB for button128 , PL for button130 ....

getCitys returns a list of citys and populates a datagrid according to a 2 letter code it is a php sevice

is there a way i could get the clickHandler to supply the value to getCitys function according to which button is pressed off the id of the button say

Comment: Yes.  But I'm not sure what data you need to pass.  Show the code for your buttons.   What does getCitys do? What kind of value does it expect?

Comment: You could always store the current button id in a class member when a button is clicked, and then access it in your dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler method.

Comment: sorry i dont really understand if you could give an example of what your talking about i might better understand but like i say my first flash application

Comment: Have you tried to send it's id in the function call itself like `button_clickHandler_100(this.id)`. It think it will help you to identify which button dispatches the event and from that you can set whatever value you would like to, using simple conditions.

Comment: the solution to this was to get rid of the creation completehandler and create a new click hanldler each button with the different value of each button bound to the click handler